# Co Prime Numbers less than N

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers

I need to find all the numbers that are coprime to a given $N$ and less than $N$.
Note that $N$ can be as large as $10^9.$ For example, numbers coprime to $5$ are $1,2,3,4$.

I want an efficient algorithm to do it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you really need to find all the numbers themselves? Or the number of such numbers?

Comment: @mathlove I need to find all the numbers themseleves

Comment: Do you know the factors of $N$? Then you can use a sieve and you will need memory of $10^9$ bits or 125 Megabytes. Time required will be proportional to $N \times k$ where $k$ is the number of primes that divide $N$. Not sure you can do it any more efficiently in the general case.

Comment: @user44197 Can u please provide an algo for doing so.Suppose i have calculated factors and they are stored in array named say factor and sieve to find all primes storing primes in array say prime.

Comment: @user3001932: Please see my answer. I am sure you can find ways to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you find the prime factors $p_1, \ldots, p_k$ of $N$, you could use a sieve: start with $1 \ldots N-1$, delete all multiples of $p_1$, then all multiples of $p_2$, etc.  What's left is coprime to $N$.

Answer (score 8):

What you want is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). 
You'll find a formula there.

Comment: I think user3001932 wants to find the numbers themselves, not just how many.

Comment: I think that mathlove has provided the answer. However, you need complete factorization of $N$ to do the calculation. If, however, you do not have all the prime factors of $N$ then you have stumbled on what is considered a very difficult problem. But factoring numbers $< 10^9$ is trivial.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Enumerating all those will take a long time especially of $N$ is a product of two large primes.

Comment: @RobertIsrael yeah..u are right. I need to find all the numbers not their count

Answer (score 2):

First find the factors of it by factorisation 
second get the prime numbers involved in that say $(a,b,\ldots)$.
E.g., $18=(2^1)(3^2)$. The prime factors are $2$ and $3$.
Third formula:
     $$\text{No. of coprimes to $N$}= N(1-1/a)(1-1/b)\cdots$$

Comment: But this just finds the number of numbers less than $N$ that are coprime to $N$. OP wants the actual numbers coprime to $N$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to implement sets. We will only add numbers $<N$ to the set so any bit representation is okay.

If you know that the primes dividing $N$ then the following works:

```
S={} // Empty sets
for p in primes dividing $N$
   add p,2p,3p... to S
end for
```

If you do not know the factors of $N$ then here is one not very efficient (but not terribly inefficient) way to do it.

```
S={} // Empty set
for k=2 to N
    if k is not in the set S then
          if gcd(k,N) > 1 then
             Add the following to S: k, 2k, 3k, 4k    
           end if
     end if
 end for
```

Now all the elements in $S$ are *not* co prime to  N, so its complement is the numbers you want

Comment: A little late!  I'm not a mathematician, but your first algorithm misses the very first element of the (ordered) set: 1.  The second algorithm appears to pick it up when you take the complement of S.  Helpful to me nonetheless.